# Trying to do HW - not understanding what this author means by giving an efficient algorithm

Tags: algorithms

In this question, what exactly are they trying to ask? I.e. in the trivial case, just travel 200 miles regardless of how many miles posts there are.  The penalty is always 0. What are my constraints? Am I missing something from this question that is giving me trouble about what the author means??

See 6.2. [image: ok]

Comment: @DavidRicherby if youd like you can post your comment as your answer I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the question more carefully. You can only stop at hotels. If there isn't a hotel after 200 miles, you'll have to travel some other distance, so the penalty will be nonzero.

"Efficient" almost always means in polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical DP problem. My tip is to first write out the backtracking recurrence, and then later reason about how to memoize the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand what the total penalty of a trip would be. Read the question carefully until you understand that. For example, if distances are $50$, $100$, $50$, $100$, then you would drive $150+150$ miles to get a penalty of $50^2 + 50^2$, which is better than a single $300$ mile trip with penalty $100^2$, or $200+100$ miles which is a penalty of $0^2 + 100^2$.

To get the trip with the lowest total penalty: Find the trip with the lowest penalty from $a_0$ to $a_1$, from $a_0$ to $a_2$, from $a_0$ to $a_3$, and so on. Remember the trips and the total penalties. (In each case, you only need to remember the last drive.)

The best trip from $a_0$ to $a_0$ is obviously doing nothing. 
The best trip from $a_0$ to $a_1$ is obviously starting at $a_0$, and driving to $a_1$.

The best trip from $a_0$ to $a_k$ with $k \ge 2$ is either going directly $a_0$ to $a_k$, or doing the best trip from $a_0$ to $a_i$ for some $1 \le i \le k-1$, then travelling $a_i$ to $a_k$.

This is $O (n^2)$ trivially, but there will be obvious shortcuts.
And the algorithm is independent of how the penalty of each drive is calculated. Shortcuts probably depend on the penalty being a convex function (that is as the distance grows, the penalty first shrinks up to some minimum, then increases).

Comment: I'll keep this answer in mind but I like to try to solve it first ;-) I didn't understand the question but have yet to get the answer